# PHP при цикле do...while берет только последнее значение. Как вывести все?

Tags: php

PHP при цикле do...while берет только последнее значение. Как вывести все? В БД добавил в поле title следующие значения(по отдельности): A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I.

Вот при коде:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("ready", $connect);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs", $connect);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<?php
do {
printf("
        <table cellspacing='10'>
            <tr>
                <td>%s</td>
            </tr>
        </table>", $row['title']);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="songs.js"></script>
```

Он выводит только "I". При обновлении Заметны как A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I стоят друг под другом, но после загрузки пропадают и остается только "I". Как сделать, чтобы вывелось все???

Comment: Зачем вы дважды пишите присвоение $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)? Уберите на шестой строке этот код... и тогда думаю будет работать корректно.

Comment: и сделайте цикл с предусловием, а не как у вас...

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     printf("
        <table cellspacing='10'>
            <tr>
                <td>%s</td>
            </tr>
        </table>", $row['title']);
     }
}
```

Comment: @navi1893 предыдущий деятель с такой ошибкой, вызывал mysql_fetch_array() ещё где-то перед этим.